# REST API. search and listing using query parameters

Tags: rest

I am trying to list all objects that belong to group1

GET /objects?group=group1

and i have a resource called object and another resource called group

What should be response if group1 does not exist

(I have serached similar questions but did not find any)

Answer (score 0):

Totally depends on your use case. Its OK to either return an empty List or throw an Exception.

Depends on the business rules for your use case.